# Row heights are not same

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

[image]

I have created a table which looks like the picture below, but i am not sure is it ok or not. I mean, why is there a line gap showing after the first rows of the two rows. I marked it with red color. Or it is the right behavior?? Can anyone please tell me? I have added my code here.

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Summary of the comparison with existing approaches}
    \label{tab:Testing Results} 
    \begin{tabular}{|p{.30 cm}|p{2.2cm}|l|l|l|}
        \hline
         \multicolumn{2}{|p{2.5cm}|} {\diagbox { }{Approach}}&Lizhi [4]&Yuan [9]&Our Approach\\\hline
                      CS1 & Total Paths &6 &10 &3\\  \cline{2-5}
                     & Feasible Paths &6 &3 &3\\  \cline{2-5}
                     & Infeasible Paths &0 &7 &0 \\\hline 
                     CS2 & Total Paths &35 &6 &1\\ \cline{2-5}
                     & Feasible Paths &35 &4 &1\\ \cline{2-5}
                     & Infeasible Paths &0 &2 &0 \\\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Without the correct font/font sizes, this cannot be reproduced, generate a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Also I would use column type `l` for the first two columns, the cell contents are short enough to fit in one line, and the image shows that the given measurements for the `p` columns are wrong anyway, too short for the first column and too large for the second.

Answer (score 1):

Simplified versions of the table with less lines and aligned numbers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Summary of the comparison with existing approaches}
  \label{tab:Testing Results}
  \begin{tabular}{
    l
    l
    S[table-format=2]
    S[table-format=2]
    S[table-format=1]
  }
    \toprule
    & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Approach}\\
    \cmidrule{3-5}
    & & {Lizhi [4]}&{Yuan [9]}&{Our approach}\\
    \midrule
    CS1 & Total paths &6 &10 &3\\
        & Feasible paths &6 &3 &3\\
        & Infeasible paths &0 &7 &0 \\
    \addlinespace
    CS2 & Total paths &35 &6 &1\\
        & Feasible paths &35 &4 &1\\
        & Infeasible paths &0 &2 &0 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Further remarks:**

- A bibliography can also be done by LaTeX and `[4]` and `[9]` can be replaced by calling macro `\cite`.
- I do not see a reason for using title case. Therefore, the example uses simple sentence case for the entries in the table.
- `Our approach` might be truncated to `Our`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this table is not compiling for my project. Is there any way to solve it and show it same to my table but without the line gaps.

Comment: Probably you have forgotten to load the required packages (the error message would have give a hint, what is missing. Where is your [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Hello! May I ask how you make those screenshots with the transparent backgrounds? (I'm asking because I like your ones)

Comment: @SkeletonBow The PDF file is processed with ghostscript's device `pngalpha`. Then, the PNG is included as blockquote for the separating lines and background.

Comment: That's perfect! Danke sehr!